# Application error deploying my node.js project on Heroku

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, heroku, econnrefused

When running heroku --tail logs I get the following error response :

error:

```
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153750+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153750+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153751+00:00 app[web.1]: parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153751+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153751+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153751+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153751+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153751+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153752+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 5432
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153752+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153752+00:00 app[web.1]: original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153753+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153753+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153753+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153753+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153753+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153753+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 5432
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153754+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-01-25T19:10:06.153754+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-01-25T19:10:06.157055+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/novousuario" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=c3ebdbb3-6831-493f-b8f1-8b02b051b0fd fwd="186.194.175.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=39ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-01-25T19:10:06.285294+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-01-25T19:10:06.378171+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-01-25T19:10:06.394935+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-01-25T19:10:08.964699+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-01-25T19:10:10.224154+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-25T19:10:10.224168+00:00 app[web.1]: > crud-tsnode@1.0.0 start
2022-01-25T19:10:10.224168+00:00 app[web.1]: > node dist/server.js
2022-01-25T19:10:10.224169+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-25T19:10:10.850373+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-01-25T19:14:21.409016+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=d43d2faa-2dc7-4ccd-b0b0-6953fb887da1 fwd="177.223.108.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=302 bytes=258 protocol=https
2022-01-25T19:14:21.565056+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/cadastro" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=631aaea8-c6eb-40b9-88d4-7443f498b302 fwd="177.223.108.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=2021 protocol=https
2022-01-25T19:14:21.764188+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/home.css" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=ab9ebd5f-dc2e-49ae-af5f-7341971cd7ce fwd="177.223.108.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=4576 protocol=https
2022-01-25T19:14:21.767993+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/user.css" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=733a9bbc-1ed0-44aa-9707-d0f92078c8eb fwd="177.223.108.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=2997 protocol=https
2022-01-25T19:14:22.539670+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/bcg.png" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=11255b2d-cbc6-4dfe-a1e0-6c800951e32d fwd="177.223.108.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=235792 protocol=https
2022-01-25T19:14:22.542372+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/email.png" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=bdcdd608-9f75-4f6d-a122-93c5ef6d82e5 fwd="177.223.108.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=18008 protocol=https
2022-01-25T19:14:22.816037+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/logo.png" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=311d663c-c948-40cc-91c9-17ce7aa7911a fwd="177.223.108.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=2388 protocol=https
2022-01-25T19:14:22.818541+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/name.png" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=d671647e-f942-4aea-a776-5832d2bee694 fwd="177.223.108.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=12497 protocol=https
2022-01-25T19:14:22.825365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/age.png" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=60241f72-2f73-4fe0-bd2f-952bf8f5a6d9 fwd="177.223.108.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=16444 protocol=https
2022-01-25T19:49:47.981231+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2022-01-25T19:49:47.986454+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2022-01-25T19:49:50.160588+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-01-25T19:49:50.389620+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2022-01-25T22:46:29.540970+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2022-01-25T22:46:29.550645+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2022-01-25T22:46:33.398737+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-01-25T22:46:34.700830+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-25T22:46:34.700973+00:00 app[web.1]: > crud-tsnode@1.0.0 start
2022-01-25T22:46:34.700974+00:00 app[web.1]: > node dist/server.js
2022-01-25T22:46:34.700977+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-25T22:46:35.247674+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-01-25T22:46:36.627250+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=1fec680e-4018-429b-976c-4fa723a293e8 fwd="186.194.175.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=302 bytes=258 protocol=https
2022-01-25T22:46:36.788688+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/cadastro" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=2325bbd9-d70d-474f-8bfb-8fe51a07c60f fwd="186.194.175.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=2021 protocol=https
2022-01-25T22:46:37.002494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/home.css" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=c51796ed-faf1-401f-8670-3d57ee5130a2 fwd="186.194.175.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=4576 protocol=https
2022-01-25T22:46:37.147871+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/user.css" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=d98f6cd2-064d-4dc2-84e6-a0ac83effa49 fwd="186.194.175.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2022-01-25T22:46:37.327082+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/bcg.png" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=e6766750-c7c3-4b5a-a9c6-c872d4af4bab fwd="186.194.175.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=235792 protocol=https
2022-01-25T22:46:37.328041+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/email.png" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=306aceb2-9e0b-418e-b276-33479a270ad4 fwd="186.194.175.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=18008 protocol=https
2022-01-25T22:46:37.582686+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/name.png" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=25b9cae2-fb7f-4e89-8a0b-3de030fb9391 fwd="186.194.175.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=12497 protocol=https
2022-01-25T22:46:37.611328+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/age.png" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=912a75a1-f82a-4fea-99e0-c88eed20c88b fwd="186.194.175.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=16444 protocol=https
2022-01-25T22:46:37.861955+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/logo.png" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=394eb964-0efa-4cc6-84e2-c1007629f51e fwd="186.194.175.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=2388 protocol=https
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833799+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/sequelize/dist/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:130
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833826+00:00 app[web.1]: reject(new sequelizeErrors.ConnectionRefusedError(err));
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833827+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833827+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833827+00:00 app[web.1]: ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833828+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._connectionCallback (/app/node_modules/sequelize/dist/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:130:24)
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833828+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:305:19)
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833829+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._handleErrorEvent (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:315:19)
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833829+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.emit (node:events:390:28)
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833830+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.reportStreamError (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:52:12)
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833830+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833830+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833831+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833831+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833831+00:00 app[web.1]: parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833831+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833832+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833832+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833832+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833833+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833833+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 5432
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833833+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833834+00:00 app[web.1]: original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833834+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833834+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833834+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833835+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833835+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833835+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 5432
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833835+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-01-25T22:46:43.833835+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-01-25T22:46:43.841412+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/novousuario" host=penedocrud.herokuapp.com request_id=0b79d914-ec57-42c9-ab36-d274157b9913 fwd="186.194.175.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=393ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-01-25T22:46:44.010251+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-01-25T22:46:44.064573+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-01-25T22:46:44.068523+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-01-25T22:46:47.824479+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-01-25T22:46:48.950210+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-25T22:46:48.950226+00:00 app[web.1]: > crud-tsnode@1.0.0 start
2022-01-25T22:46:48.950227+00:00 app[web.1]: > node dist/server.js
2022-01-25T22:46:48.950227+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-25T22:46:49.481570+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Here is my server.ts file:

```
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import mustache from 'mustache-express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import mainRoutes from './routes/index';

dotenv.config();

const server = express();
server.set('view engine', 'mustache');
server.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
server.engine('mustache', mustache());

server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
server.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
server.use(mainRoutes);
server.use((req: Request, res: Response)=>{
    res.status(404).render('pages/404')
});
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

my routes:

```
import { Router } from "express";
import * as HomeController from '../controllers/homeController'
import * as UserController from '../controllers/userController'
import * as SearchController from '../controllers/searchController'

const router = Router()
router.get('/', HomeController.home)
router.get('/cadastro', HomeController.register)
router.get('/usuarios', UserController.users)
router.post('/novousuario', UserController.newUser)
router.get('/usuario/:id/editar', UserController.editUser)
router.get('/usuario/:id/excluir', UserController.deleteUser)
router.post('/novousuarioeditado/:id', UserController.newEditUser)
router.get('/search', SearchController.search)

export default router
```

looking through the browser it shows the error 503, there seems to be something wrong with the routes, when registering in the CRUD app, it should request the POST route and immediately redirect it to the users, but it simply gives an error in the application

remembering that everything is working locally, with no apparent errors

and , here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "crud-tsnode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "postinstall": "npm run tsc && copyfiles -u 1 src/**/*.mustache dist/",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start-dev": "nodemon -e ts,json,mustache src/server.ts"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/FabioPenedo/Crud-tsnode.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/FabioPenedo/Crud-tsnode/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/FabioPenedo/Crud-tsnode#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^14.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "mustache-express": "^1.3.2",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "sequelize": "^6.13.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/mustache-express": "^1.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.10",
    "@types/sequelize": "^4.28.11",
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: None of the code you shared above is relevant. This is a database connection error; your database won't be on localhost on Heroku. Where do you configure that? Are you using Knex or something?

Comment: I really saw that the problem was this, I have to configure my environment variables, .env that is being used in the code, and I already have the database created locally, the intention is how to upload it to heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Port 5432 hints that your program is trying to connect to postgreSQL on localhost. That's probably the way it works in development on your own machine.

But, on Heroku your postgreSQL server is not on the same machine as your web dyno, so connecting to localhost:5432 does not work. The [econnrefused](/questions/tagged/econnrefused) error comes from the operating system, and it says that nothing is running on the port you tried to connect to.

Heroku, when you [provision a postgreSQL database instance](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres), gives you an environment variable called `DATABASE_URL` that's available to your app. You should use that to connect to your database.

Comment: I got this DATABASE_URL, I used the information from this db in the cloud, I connected to the dbeaver client, made the connection, created the tables and columns, when entering the application and when he needs to access the route to create the user, he gives an error, I understand that is not yet fully connected, remembering my Application is a CRUD, made with nodejs(express), typescript, and I used sequelize, I used dotenv, to create the environment variables, and there in heroku I also created these variables and put the information that the cloud bank provides me, what will be missing?